# Creating lists from elements in a bigger list

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have a list whose size is a multiple of 16. What I want to do is go through the list and get 16 elements and create a list from those values, and then store those values somewhere. After that I can either ignore them or remove  them from the list, and continue this process until the bigger list is empty. What I was trying to do was to go through the list, and keep a counter of some sort to keep track of the number of elements that have been appended to the list. However, I have been stuck from there. Any ideas on how to accomplish on what I am trying to do? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
lst = [[1, 4, 0], [2, 4, 0], [3, 4, 0], [4, 4, 0], [1, 3, 0], [2, 3, 0], [3, 3, 0], [4, 3, 0], [1, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0], [3, 2, 0], [4, 2, 0], [1, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [3, 1, 0], [4, 1, 0],[1, 4, 0], [2, 4, 0], [3, 4, 0], [4, 4, 0], [1, 3, 0], [2, 3, 0], [3, 3, 0], [4, 3, 0], [1, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0], [3, 2, 0], [4, 2, 0], [1, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [3, 1, 0], [4, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, and tell us where you have problems (in the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. After clicking on random links on the right hand side I came to answer that did exactly what I needed to happen.
Here is the solution to my problem:

```
[input[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(input), n)]
```

The solution above goes through input and creates a list of size n.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you start with a list of size n, where n % 16 == 0. You want to end with n/16 lists of size 16. You can accomplish this pretty easily with a double for loop. The outer loop should go for n/16 iterations. the inner loop should go for 16 iterations. The outer loop creates a new list with each iteration. the inner loop takes elements from the original list and appends them to the newly created list.